# Android horizontal scroll programmatically

Tags: android, layout, tabs, horizontalscrollview

In Android, I want to create a particular control which may require to set the location of a component by fixed coordinates.

This is what I want to do. These screenshot are taken from a swing application of mine. I want to clone the buttons on top and their behaviour, into an android application. Basically if there are too many buttons in the menubar, left and/or right arrows appear, and clicking on them will scroll horizontally to access the hidden buttons.

[image: screenshot]

I need to be able to set the coordinates of an horizontal linear layout inside another one, and even to set negative coordinates in order to scroll on the right.

I'm doing this using a null layout in swing. Can I achieve this with Android ?
I'm not sure if an `HorizontalScrollView` can do this. Could someone point out a good tutorial or something related to what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a HorizontalScrollView can achieve what you intend to do with your Menu Bar. You don't need these "scroll" Buttons, because a user can swipe the menu. 
You can nest LinearLayouts together, however you want. if you want to control their flow try to apply margins to them. You can set fixed Coordinates in an AbsoluteLayout, too.

Comment: It works thanks, and there is no need for the buttons indeed. I'm new to this touch screen stuff, and you learned me something interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [gallery?](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) If not gallery, then a child or cousin of it. As far as I know, there is no ViewParent that will allow what your are shooting for.

Hope that helped ~Aedon